# Is it possible to Create stream and filter in java 7

Tags: java, java-7

I have a list

```
List<Person> persons =
    Arrays.asList(
        new Person("Max", 4),
        new Person("Peter", 2),
        new Person("Pamela", 3),
        new Person("David", 9));
```

I'd like to create Stream and filter the list by a field, something like in java 8:

```
persons
    .stream()
    .filter(p -> p.age >= 18)
```

Comment: Is it possible to create functionality that was introduced in Java 8 using Java 7. .... Let me see. Doubtful

Comment: `guava` is what I would use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `Stream` is impossible but you could still use Guava's filter ([Collections2.filter()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter(java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)) or [Iterables.filter()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Predicate-) depending on what you'll do with the result) combined with Guava's [Predicate](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html)

```
Predicate<Person> predicate = new Predicate<Person>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Person person) {
            return person.age >= 18;
        }
    };
Collection<Person> result = Collections2.filter(persons, predicate);
```

If you'd like more info about Guava's filter and transform, I got my source from here : https://www.baeldung.com/guava-filter-and-transform-a-collection